# How do I test Cloudflare IPs?

Tags: networking, internet, troubleshooting, cloudflare

With some troubleshooting with regards to some cloudflare websites not loading properly, I came to understand that it is an issue with my ISP. No issues occurred with another ISP's internet (mobile data), and with the ISP in question, using a VPN eliminates the issues.

I am going to call them and report to them but I don’t know what to tell them as to what isn’t exactly working. As the websites I am having issues with are loading, but time to time they don’t load, so I can’t give the websites as they would assume it is working.

How can I test the Cloudflare IPs and figure out which ones are problematic when using my ISP’s internet? Is is these? https://www.cloudflare.com/ips/

If so how do I do it, I am not very fluent in networking.

Comment: Cloudflare uses Anycast, so the hosts those IPs refer to is most likely radically different for your mobile and landline ISPs.

Comment: Oh I see, in that case what do I do from here? Is there anything I can do on my end or is there something my ISP must do?

Comment: I suggest following [these instructions from Cloudflare](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/203118044-Gathering-information-for-troubleshooting-sites) even if they're targeted mostly at admins. You can then contact Cloudflare or your ISP with the information you obtained.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I tried those including HAR files and such. But eventually I just thought I'd call my ISP and give them an example website as I figured their technicians would figure it out, and it is fixed as of now I believe! It works fine for about 2 hours or so, so far